# Logback: separate logging WARN / TRACE

Tags: java, logback

I'm trying to configure logback to print:
- everything (level trace or debug) to the screen
- everything (level trace or debug) to the debugfile
- warnings and above to an error file

My logback.xml config is like this:

```
...
<logger name="be" level="TRACE">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>
```

However, the error and debug file contain exactly the same, being ALL logging (debug and error). I've already tried to play with the additivity option, but that's apparently not what I need.

The second question is that I use name "be" to have all classes under be.* but actually I want to capture everything there (com.*  as well).

Comment: off topic: Ugh, don't do that. You'll have to have three separate files open to figure out what's going on. And if it's running on a remote machine, you either download three files separately or have three terminals open. And it's getting even worse, if you roll your logfiles daily and you have to figure out what's going on during midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by adding a filter to the appender:

```
    <appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
       <!-- deny all events with a level below WARNING -->
       <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
           <level>WARN</level>
       </filter>
```